# How to provide an auto-committing transaction for „USING PERIODIC COMMIT“ on Neo4jRepository in Neo4j?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

### Target:

Programmatic, daily recurring import of 20 million records from a CSV file into Neo4j.

### Environment:

- Neo 4.2.3, Enterprise Edition.
- Spring Boot v2.4.2

### Initial situation:

- Using Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) and spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j.
- Data set import via custom query of a `Neo4jRepository` (DAO):

---

```
@Repository
public interface ImportDataDAO extends Neo4jRepository<Molecule, Long> {
  @Transactional
  @Query("USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500\n" +
      "CALL apoc.load.csv( $url, {mapping: $mapping} ) yield map AS row\n" +
      "MERGE (molecule:Molecule {moleculeId: row.moleculeId})\n" +
      "  ON CREATE SET molecule = row\n")
  void importData(
      @Param("url") String url,
      @Param("mapping") Map<String, Map<String, Object>> mapping
  );
}
```

- To avoid out of memory errors use `Using Periodic Commit 500`.
- Resulting error: `org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Executing queries that use periodic commit in an open transaction is not possible.`

### Discussion:

`Periodic Commit` is one of the few functions that requires an auto-commiting transaction, however through Spring via `@Transactional` only a normal one is provided. In Neo4j Browser I can prepend `:auto` to `Using Periodic Commit`, the import will be executed successfully. At the `@Transactional` annotation I can specify `Propagation` and `Isolation` features among others, but I don't see a way to define an auto-commiting transaction for the custom query.

### To be solved problem:

How can I use `Periodic Commit` from above mentioned custom query for CSV import?

Comment: Possible workaround: usage of `CALL apoc.periodic.iterate` instead of `Using Periodic Commit`.

Comment: I think repositories are the wrong layer of abstraction for this kind of tasks.
Use either Neo4jClient or the raw driver for this kind of things.